# Docusign approach for uploading one document and multiple supplemental document through SDK

Tags: docusignapi

I have started new with DocuSign integration. I am planning to use c# SDK. 
Now I have to upload one document and multiple supplemental document in an envelope. Also there will be multiple signer as well. The document size may vary from 10MB to 25 MB (as there is a retraction on size, I am restricting max size to 25 mb)

I am thinking about the following approaches.

First

1. Put everything in single envelope and send the request. Here I am not sure with multiple files with large size, how long it will take (I may need to explore chunk upload for this approach)

Second

1. Create draft Envelope with initial settings. Get the envelope id.
2. Add the documents one by one in envelope. This will be in parallel.
3. Add Recipients (this can go with #1 as well)
4. Send update request to change the status to "sent"

Please let me know your thoughts - which route I should take. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either pattern will work depending on issues due to the size of your document(s) in an envelope.

Note that the SDKs current send documents by using base64 encoding. This further restricts the max size of documents in a single API transaction due to the base64 encoding overhead.

Due to your document size and base64 encoding issues, I recommend that you use your second pattern.